# xargs to execute a string - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: shell, eval, xargs

I'm trying to rename all files in current directory such that upper case name is converted to lower. I'm trying to do it like this:

```
ls -1|gawk '{print "`mv "$0" "tolower($0)"`"}'|xargs -i -t eval {}
```

I have two files in the directory, Y and YY
-t added for debugging, and output is:

```
eval `mv Y y`
xargs: eval: No such file or directory
```

if I execute the eval on its own, it works and moves Y to y.

I know there are other ways to achieve this, but I'd like to get this working if I can!
Cheers

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[eval](http://www.softpanorama.org/Utilities/eval.shtml) is a shell [builtin command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin), not a standalone executable. Thus, `xargs` cannot run it directly. You probably want:

```
ls -1 | gawk '{print "`mv "$0" "tolower($0)"`"}' | xargs -i -t sh -c "{}"
```

Comment: Realised you don't need the eval (or the `s) with this method. so     ls -1 | gawk '{print "mv "$0" "tolower($0)}' | xargs -i -t sh -c "{}" works as well

Comment: it doesn't work for me when coming from a sed replace which outputs a docker pull xx: `sed -n 's/\s*image: \(.*\)/docker pull \1/gp' ../docker-compose.yml |xargs -i -0 -t sh -c "{}"`.  I get 'Invalid reference format'. I also tried putting double quotes before the xargs

Comment: Using sh -c unfortunately doesn't preserve the shell variables that aren't exported, as it executes in a new process

Answer (score 4):

Although you're looking at an xargs solution, another method to perform the same thing can be done with `tr` (assuming sh/bash/ksh syntax):

```
for i in *; do mv $i `echo $i | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`; done
```

Comment: yes, that's probably the best one - it a colleague's similar code, but split over several lines, and using a variable - which prompted the question - can you do it in 1 line? I then got distracted by trying to get xargs to work

Comment: Yep -- what I've dropped above will work without modification. No matter what you're dealing with, semi-colons are the statement separator if you want to combine multiple statements on one line.

Answer (score 1):

If your files are created by creative users, you will see files like:

```
My brother's 12" records
```

The solutions so far do not work on that kind of files. If you have GNU Parallel installed this will work (even on the files with creative names):

```
ls | parallel 'mv {} "$(echo {} | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]")"'
```

Watch the intro video to learn more: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval with xargs like the one below.

Note: I only tested this in bash shell

```
ls -1| gawk '{print "mv "$0" /tmp/"toupper($0)""}'| xargs -I {} sh -c "eval {}"
```

or

```
ls -1| gawk '{print "mv "$0" /tmp/"toupper($0)""}'| xargs -I random_var_name sh -c "eval random_var_name"
```

I generally use this approach when I want to avoid one-liner for loop.

e.g.

```
for file in $(find /some/path | grep "pattern");do somecmd $file; done
```

The same can be written like below

```
find /some/path | grep "pattern"| xargs -I {} sh -c "somecmd {}"
```